# JPA EclipseLink Custom Entity/Object as IN Parameter

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I have stored procedures working when i pass in basic java objects (String, Long, etc.) but i cant seem to pass in my own Entity/Object without getting the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
Error Code: 17004
Call: BEGIN sar_ops.input_rule_no_response(operation_id_in=>?, executing_usr_id_in=>?, rule_obj_in=>?, success_ind_out=>?, error_cur_out=>?); END;
    bind => [MO1234ABCD, TEST, Rule [id=99999, last_updated_by=mike], => success_ind_out, => error_cur_out]
Query: ResultSetMappingQuery(name="input_rule_no_response" )
```

From reading up i thought my code would work (see below). I added the @Struct annotation and gave it the name of the matching oracle object from the Database. I was under the impression from the eclispelink documentation i would only need the @Embeddable and @Struct annotations on my class, but i have also added the @Entity annotation whilst testing a theory but still get the same error. I feel i must be missing some form of configuration for eclipselink to know that the object im passing in is a Java class representation of the Oracle object it expects.

Oracle Object and stored proc definition:

```
PROCEDURE input_rule_no_response
   (
      operation_id_in     IN operation_id_type
     ,executing_usr_id_in IN usr_id%TYPE
     ,rule_obj_in         IN rule_obj_type
     ,success_ind_out     OUT uttype.boolean_type
     ,error_cur_out       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
   ) IS
...

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rule_obj_type AS OBJECT
(
   id                 NUMBER(10),
   last_updated_by        VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

My stored procedure is defined as:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="input_rule_no_response",
        resultClasses={DBError.class, Rule.class},
        procedureName="sar_ops.input_rule_no_response",
        parameters={
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name="operation_id_in", mode=ParameterMode.IN, type=String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name="executing_usr_id_in", mode=ParameterMode.IN, type=String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name="rule_obj_in", mode=ParameterMode.IN, type=Rule.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name="success_ind_out", mode=ParameterMode.OUT, type=Character.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name="error_cur_out", mode=ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type=void.class)
})
```

And my entity looks like:

```
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Struct(name="rule_obj_type", fields={"id","last_updated_by"})
public class Rule implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4768354320081279604L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="last_updated_by")
    private String last_updated_by;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLast_updated_by() {
        return last_updated_by;
    }

    public void setLast_updated_by(String last_updated_by) {
        this.last_updated_by = last_updated_by;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rule [id=" + id + ", last_updated_by="
                + last_updated_by + "]";
    }
}
```

And my execute code:

```
public boolean inputRuleNoResponse(Rule sar) {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("input_rule_no_response");
        query.setParameter("operation_id_in", "MO1234ABCD");
        query.setParameter("executing_usr_id_in", "TEST");
        query.setParameter("rule_obj_in", sar);
        return query.execute();
}
```

Comment: The StoredProcedureParameter type is used to specify the java type you want back when the database value needs to be converted to java.  I think you are missing the jdbcType and JdbcTypeName http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_storedprocedureparameter.htm

Comment: Thanks, adding the jdbcType and JdbcTypeName worked and i am now able to get objects in and saved correctly... next step is getting them back out again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to add the JdbcType and JdbcTypeName to the stored procedure configuration as suggested by Chris.